# Load test run in Jenkins with Jmeter does not end

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, devops, blazemeter

I'm trying to run load tests on Jenkins through Jmeter (with Blazemeter). I've installed:

- Install Jenkins on a machine that you have access to
- Install the Jenkins Performance Plugin on the machine with Jenkins
- Install Taurus on the Jenkins machine
- Install Apache JMeter™ on our local machine

The only file that initially exists in the project folder is the blazedemo_script. jmx script generated in Jmeter and that works perfectly in this software.

The execution never ends. And I also don't understand why you can't find the modified file it generates if you enter it in the same directory.

Thank you very much.

I get the following log:

```html
Lanzada por el usuario e73dbef17ee24d5c96bb99b8c598de0c

Ejecutando.en el espacio de trabajo C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\blazermeter

[WARNING] Performance test: Job workspace contains spaces in path. Virtualenv does not support such path. Creating temporary workspace for virtualenv.

Performance test: Checking global bzt installation...

[blazermeter] $ bzt --help

Performance test: Found global bzt installation.

Performance test: run [bzt, blazedemo_script.jmx, C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\blazermeter\jenkins-report.yml]

[blazermeter] $ bzt blazedemo_script.jmx "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\blazermeter\jenkins-report.yml"

13:24:19 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.10.5

13:24:19 INFO: Starting with configs: ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\workspace\\blazermeter\\jenkins-report.yml', 'c:\\windows\\temp\\jmx_52sdqz.json']

13:24:19 INFO: Configuring...

13:24:19 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\blazermeter\2018-02-20_13-24-19.717000

13:24:19 INFO: Preparing...

13:24:20 WARNING: Failed to detect plugins for C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\blazermeter\modified_blazedemo_script-1.jmx: [Error 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

13:24:20 INFO: Starting...

13:24:20 INFO: Waiting for results...
```

Comment: It failed to find `modified_blazedemo_script-1.jmx`

Comment: I know it can't find it. It is a file that generates automatically as I comment in my post. It generates it in the same directory and that happens. The only file I insert in the folder is blazedemo_script. jmx.

I'm trying now with a Taurus config file and I get the same error.

Thank you

Comment: you don't use include controller in your script?

Comment: can you show your Taurus config?

Comment: Thanks @user7294900! Finally I solved this issue weeks ago. But I forgot to mention the solution; I just added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem using the following command and script in jenkins:

```
Shell Script -- bzt xxxx.yml -o scenarios.xxxx-webapp.variables.port-number=8080 -o scenarios.xxxx-webapp.variables.server-name=xxxx-es-web-stable-12-app -o scenarios.xxxx-mobile.variables.port-number=8080 -o scenarios.xxxx-mobile.variables.server-name=xxxx-es-web-stable-12-app -o modules.console.disable=true -o settings.artifacts-dir=./results --
```

Attached the configuration yml file:

```
execution:
- scenario: xxxxxx-webapp
- scenario: xxxxxx-mobile

scenarios:
  xxxxxx-webapp:
    script: ./xxxxxx_WEBAPP/xxxxxx_WEBAPP.jmx
    variables:
      server-name: localhost
      port-number: 9090
      num-users: 1
      ramp: 10
  xxxxxx-mobile:
    script: ./xxxxxx_ANDROIDAPP/xxxxxx_ANDROIDAPP.jmx
    variables:
      server-name: localhost
      port-number: 9090
      num-users: 3
      ramp: 10
```

Comment: Which specific part of this answer addresses the problem in which the execution never ends? I'm having the same problem but I'm not sure what you did to solve it.